# Why ist setuptools not installing install_requires

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

My Python package is installed using setuptools configured with a setup.cfg file. In it requirements are specified:

```
[options]
packages = find:
zip_safe = True
include_package_data = True
install_requires =
    gmsh >= 4.10.5
    matplotlib >= 3.6.1
    numpy >= 1.23.3
```

When installing the package via pip the package to a fresh venv non of the requirements are installed. The output of pip show no errors or related information. However, once manually installing them everything works fine. How can I get pip to actually install the requirements?

Comment: The syntax looks correct. Do you also have a `pyproject.toml` file, which might be stealing focus?

Comment: I have both files. As far as I understand setuptools I need both as it throws an exeption that I need setup.py or pyproject.toml after trying to remove pyproject.toml. I have tried to also add the requires to pyproject.toml. This did not heltp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mentioned in the comments that you have a `pyproject.toml` file. If you use the toml configuration then you do not need the `setup.cfg` at all. Delete the `setup.cfg` and add in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = ...
version = ...
dependencies = [
    "gmsh >= 4.10.5",
    "matplotlib >= 3.6.1",
    "numpy >= 1.23.3",
]
```